# How to use test -h or test -L on OSX?

Tags: macos, bash, shell, symbolic-link

I'm trying to detect in a shell script if a file is a symlink pointing to a directory. This is what I'm doing:

```
if [[ -L "$out_dir" && -d "$out_dir" ]]
then
    echo "Dir is a symlink"
else
    echo "Dir is not a symlink"
fi
```

However, this fails. Some experimentation:

```
bash-3.2$ ls -ail ..
total 16
8004466 drwxr-xr-x  10 username  1177235957  340 Jul 18 15:41 ./
1020189 drwxr-xr-x  10 username  1177235957  340 Jul 18 15:16 ../
8004467 drwxr-xr-x  12 username  1177235957  408 Jul 18 15:16 .git/
8004528 -rw-r--r--   1 username  1177235957  501 Jul 18 15:16 .gitignore
8004919 lrwxr-xr-x   1 username  1177235957   22 Jul 18 15:41 Dependencies -> ../../lmi/Dependencies
```

so `../Dependencies`, according to ls, is a symlink, however:

```
bash-3.2$ test -L ../Dependencies
bash-3.2$ echo $?
0
bash-3.2$ test -h ../Dependencies
bash-3.2$ echo $?
0
```

Shouldn't both of these return 1? Am I misunderstanding something about how this is supposed to work? How can accomplish my goal, which is detecting if a file is a symlink pointing to a directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exit values from your experiment are correct. When the `test` utility evaluates an expression, if the expression evaluates to true, `test` returns a ***zero (true)*** exit status; otherwise it returns ***1 (false)***.

So, in your example, `test -L ../Dependencies` returns 0 (true) because `../Dependencies` is a symbolic link. If `../Dependencies` ***was not*** a symbolic link, `test` would return 1 (false).

The shell script `if` statement is correct, but you can add `echo` commands to see if there are other problems when the shell script runs. For example, you might add two `echo` commands before the `if` statement:

```
echo "path is '$PWD'"
echo "out_dir is '$out_dir'"
```

Comment: I tried that and both are correct. Furthermore, I can use readlink on the link and it displays correct information. That said, you are probably right in saying that the problem lies somewhere else, so this answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with a more convoluted solution (since that suits my personality, but that's not important now...)

```
for x in $(ls -lp|egrep ^[dl].*\/$); do 
   case $(echo $x|cut -c 1) in 
      "d") echo "This is a dir";; 
      "l") echo "This is a link";;
   esac
done
```

Briefly, `ls -lp` prints long format with a trailing slash for all directories. The very first character of long format tells us the mode (`d` for directories, `l` for link, `-` for regular files, etc). Given this info, we can use `egrep` to filter our `ls` for listings of directories and links that end in a `/` and use `case` to further filter our list. Note: This loop will also filter out linked files because of the `-p` option in `ls`

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with the following solution:

```
function is_sym_link()
{
    readlink $1 > /dev/null
    return $?
}
```

It might not cover all cases, but for my environment it's sufficient. I don't know why the original didn't work, unfortunately.